# Call function from promise, _this2 is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, oauth-2.0

Currently I'm working on a React Native project with OAuth 2.0 authentication. Unfortunately I keep getting the error **_this2.accesTokenReceived is not a function**. I'm binding the function in the constructor as follows:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.accessTokenReceived = this.accessTokenReceived.bind(this);
}
```

My API-call is as follows in the API.js file. The token is successfully received.

```
export const login = (code) => {
    return fetch('https://url.com')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {

            console.log('API login access_token: ' + responseJson['response']['access_token']);
            return responseJson['response']['access_token'];

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            throw error;
        });
};
```

When the user is returned to the app the following code gets executed within the openURL function.

```
 Api.login(code)
        .then(token => {
            this.accessTokenReceived(token);

        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log('api call error');
            alert(error.message);
        });
```

I would like to call the accesTokenReceived function to navigate the user to a new window and do some other stuff. This is when I get the error. Can someone explain to me why I'm getting this error, Am I binding the function incorrect?

Comment: `this` on `this.accessTokenReceived` is bind to the function context not the instance. [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: This fixed my problem, i get it now. Thanks!